# MySQL sorting not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have one table named companies as below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

and MySQL talbe data for this table is as below.

```
INSERT INTO `companies` (`id`, `user_id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 2, 'Mylan'),
(2, 1, 'Intas'),
(3, 48, 'Glenmark'),
(4, 21, 'Amipharma'),
(5, 1, 'XEPA SOUL');
```

now when i sort record using below query

```
SELECT * FROM companies ORDER BY name ASC;
```

this i returnning.

- XEPA SOUL
- Amipharma
- Glenmark
- Intas
- Mylan

and this is wrong as `X` is coming first and its must be shown last.

I do not know why its like this.

Please give some hint or explanation so i could correct this.

Thanks

Comment: if everything you have is exactly like you posted, it WILL work. so i think its not. for example: you are not actually doing the ORDER BY or "XEPA SOUL" got some whitespace in front

Comment: I think,May be a blank space inserted before "X" in "XEPA SOUL"

Comment: @x4rf41 please post it as answer...

Comment: what is the answer? i just gave you some suggestions

Comment: @x4rf41 extra space...That was the problem.

Comment: Voting to close. The provided `INSERT INTO` clauses do not have any space—this question is not going to help others.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yes you are right because when i exported database data that time it comes without having space...and i do not know why..? but when i edit it in phpmyadmin that shows extra space...thats is not my fault..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove left spaces by using LTRIM(),

```
  SELECT * FROM companies ORDER BY LTRIM(name) ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

For best result you can use orderby for id

SELECT * FROM companies ORDER BY id ASC;

Answer (score 1):

As other sayed in the comment, I think that you have an extra blank space in front of XEPA SOUL. If you want, you can [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) your data in the `ORDER BY` clausule:

```
SELECT * FROM companies ORDER BY TRIM(name) ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The default character set and collation are latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string  are case insensitive by default. This is problem with the collation setting.
Try with this

SELECT * FROM companies ORDER BY  CONVERT (name USING latin2) ASC

Comment: This is a nice answer for an invalid question. All samples in the question start with an uppercase letter so it isn't a collation issue.